# Is it possible to see the PP and BP of an opponent without fighting him?

Tags: steam, ultra-street-fighter-iv

When you play against an opponent you see their PP and BP. You can also show the PP in the lobby by selecting the menu point.

Can I somehow see the BP and PP of my friends or somebody else I have played before without actually fighting against them?

Also, is it possible to see the BP of all of other peoples' characters?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, technically you can, but only from the time period in which you played them. If you go to your battle log by going to Multiplayer Battle > Replay Channel > Battle Log, you can see both the PP and the BP of the player you had played against.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Are they updated? Lets say his stats are 2000 BP and 1000 PP (today) when I played against him. Then he plays like crazy for 2 days and now his stats are 3000 BP and 1500 PP. Which stats would I see in the battle log after 2 days?

Comment: @ayckoster No, they only reflect the PP and BP of the player when you played against them, and they don't update.